# Kingston MobileLite G4 no longer working with SD card

Tags: drivers, usb, sd-card

Kingston MobileLite G4 lists (lsusb) as:
Realtek Semiconductor Corp. Card reader
0bda:0326
System: Fossa

It is no longer working with my MicroSD card when contained in its usual SD card converter straight from the camera. Until recently I had been using it successfully for several years.

It shows in Ubuntu/Disks app as two devices but no longer seem mountable.

Answer (score 0):

The Kingston provides its own microsd slot and this is still working.  So still good for main camera files and with mobile phone storage card.

Comment: An older G3 not G4 model also now has similar behaviour.  
Kingston MobileLite G3 lists (lsusb) as: Realtek Semiconductor Corp. Card reader 0bda:0306 System: Fossa